# Git: not found despite installed in usb on OpenWRT?

Tags: linux, git, usb, openwrt

I'm trying to compile my own package and using git clone.

```
root@LEDE:/mnt/sda1/lede-sdk-17.01.2-ar71xx-nand_gcc-5.4.0_musl-1.1.16.Linux-x86_64/package# git https://...
-ash: git: not found
```

So I installed git on my USB drive:

```
root@LEDE:~# opkg install -d usb git
```

Installed without fail.

But then I try running git, it returned the same message:

```
-ash: git: not found
```

Even though it is installed on usb:

```
root@LEDE:~# opkg install git
Package git (2.11.0-1) installed in usb is up to date.
```

Comment: Minor hint: `$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

You either need to include the path you installed the program to in your $path variable or just run the executable by calling it's full path. I'm not sure where the usb folder is located but it could be `usb/git clone example.com` or `/usb/git clone example.com`